# Change WCF endpoint based on the selected environment (TEST/UAT/PROD)

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, runtime, endpoint

I've found a number of ways to change an endpoint at runtime, but nothing exactly matches what I'm trying to do. I have a number of defined endpoints for various WCF services in a WinForms .NET 4.8 project. What I would like to do is have the user select the environment in which they want to work and have the system then refresh and use the endpoints for the selected environment. Currently, we have different app.configs which are used for each environment, and the build process takes care of all of this, but I would much rather have one version with a changeable environment than three different versions. Is this more trouble than it's worth? Also, I'd like to accomplish this without having to restart the application.

Comment: My recommendation is to configure the WCF service relative to each working environment. Finally, connect to the relative WCF service according to the working environment read by app.config in the winform project.